# how to get a ViewModel instance inside another ViewModel withKoin

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I am new to koin and kotlin and I have just started using koin in my project and It is working quite good. I have two viewmodel classes, SubscritpionViewModel and LoginViewModel. Is there a way I can get instance of LoginViewModel inside SubscriptionViewModel. I don't know if it is right or not but it will be handy for me if I can access the other viewmodel.

```
val viewModule = module {
   viewModel { SubscriptionViewModel(get(), get()) }
   viewModel { LoginViewModel(get()) }
}
```

SubscriptionViewModel

```
class SubscriptionViewModel(val api: ServiceApi,  var user: LoginViewModel) : BaseViewModel() {
   ...
}
```

I have also created a separate module for this, but I don't know what is the right way to initialize it.

```
val userModule = module {

single( definition = {
    get<LoginViewModel>() }) 
}
```

Comment: Hey, I think it's a bad design. I think what you should do is to create a common object between LoginViewModel and SubscriptionViewModel and inject it via constructor to both LoginViewModel and SubscriptionViewModel. Maybe Repository pattern would be good? Please describe the functionality you want to implement so we can get the idea of why you need one ViewModel inside another

Comment: @MariuszBrona can you show me how to inject that common object via constructor.

Comment: I added an example in the answer

Comment: Why you add LoginViewModel into SubscriptionViewModel, It's not good

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a bad design. I think what you should do is to create a common object between LoginViewModel and SubscriptionViewModel and inject it via constructor to both LoginViewModel and SubscriptionViewModel. Maybe Repository pattern would be good? Please describe the functionality you want to implement so we can get the idea of why you need one ViewModel inside another. With repository you can do something like this:

```kotlin
class UserRepository(private val serviceApi: ServiceApi) {

}

class SubscriptionViewModel(val userRepository: UserRepository) : BaseViewModel() {
   ...
} 

class LoginViewModel(val userRepository: UserRepository) : BaseViewModel() {
 ...
}
```

and in Koin module:

```kotlin
module {
   single { UserRepository(get()) }

   viewModel { SubscriptionViewModel(get()) }
   viewModel { LoginViewModel(get()) }
}
```